# Flink: How to cancel the correct job using the command line interface?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink server which runs several streaming jobs. These jobs were started using the `flink run` command and basically run until you stop them. Now I want to cancel a specific job. When I do `flink list`, I'm getting something like this:

```
------------------ Running/Restarting Jobs -------------------
10.12.2015 08:30:37 : d6aeefaa2295ce122b65037805db0891 : Flink Streaming Job (RUNNING)
10.12.2015 08:44:18 : cfe10aca3435730d09691ff644475467 : Flink Streaming Job (RESTARTING)
10.12.2015 08:55:08 : 4ca359e286d4f5b4de62aee76f4c6389 : Flink Streaming Job (RESTARTING)
10.12.2015 08:57:42 : 1b75acb482f2610039ea2211e094b862 : Flink Streaming Job (RESTARTING)
10.12.2015 09:07:22 : 609993523b0214f52fabfdf09baf419d : Flink Streaming Job (RESTARTING)
```

Using this output it's impossible to cancel the correct job as there is no way to identify which job is which. All jobs just have *Flink Streaming Job* as their name, so I wouldn't know which one to pick.

Is there a way to change the job name that is appearing in `flink list`? If not, is there a way to get additional information about the running jobs over the command line (e.g. which JAR file it was started from, what is it's main class, etc.). If not, is there a way to get the Job-ID back from `flink run`, so I can store it in some kind of PID-file equivalent and use that ID later to cancel the Job?

Comment: Note that the REST API for job submission does provide the job ID, which may be easier to deal with than parsing the output of `flink run`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute()` method allows you to set the job's name:

```
// execute program
env.execute("Streaming data into " + topicName + " topic");
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed. Thank you very much!